# Does SO track anonymous editor statistics?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous

[image]

Are anonymous edits IP logged and tracked ? Does this show the edits made from a specific IP ?

Comment: As for "does this show edits made from a specific IP" they haven't disclosed how they track that information internally with a great deal of specificity that I'm aware of. If it did, would that discourage you from participating?

Comment: @jcolebrand I am simply asking what that stat means. I am not sure why you ask "would that discourage you from participating?". Why would it?

Comment: I mean, you have like no motive here. I'm really curious what you gain here by asking if they show by the IP. I just read your question and get a lot of "wat?" in my head.

Comment: @jcolebrand Oh, motive. I am a very inquisitive individual ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

Comment: `<!-- fluff to make the question length longer because seriously -->`

Comment: I mean, sometimes you just need a simple answer. I don't know that it was worth all the boldness and largeness, but since you thought it worthwhile as an edit I'll allow it ;-)